# pausing a jquery animation in the middle using delay. having some issues

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, background-image

```
    $('textarea.contact').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({"backgroundPosition": "+=350 -=150"}, 500).delay(500);
    $(this).animate({"backgroundPosition": "+=350 -=150"}, 500);
});
```

I'm using a background position library in order to animate a background.  I would like to have the background slide half way.  Pause in the middle, and then continue on it's way.  unfortunately when I write the code this way the animation moves half way.  pauses in the middle, and then restarts the animation from the beginning rather than incrementing.  anyone know why?

Comment: What happens when you combine both lines of code into a single chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps use a callback function like so:

```
$(this).animate({"backgroundPosition": "+=350 -=150"}, 500, function () {
    $(this).delay(500).animate({"backgroundPosition": "+=350 -=150"}, 500);
});
```

It kinda sounds like the css for the background image is not being saved after the initial animation, so maybe set the css in the callback function:

```
$(this).animate({"backgroundPosition": "+=350 -=150"}, 500, function () {
    $(this).css({"backgroundPosition": '...'});
    $(this).delay(500).animate({"backgroundPosition": "+=350 -=150"}, 500);
});
```

Comment: $(this).css({"backgroundPosition": '...'});

this wasn't necessary.  But the rest of the code did the trick.  Interesting jquery doesnt save the value without a callback function in place.  

multiple click events can increment an animation like this.  However one click event cant without a callback function.  interesting.

Comment: What plugin are you using to animate the background?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a hacking approach, but what about animating without moving:

```
$( this )
    .animate({"backgroundPosition": "+=350 -=150"}, 500)
    .animate({"backgroundPosition": "+=0 +=0"}, 500)
    .animate({"backgroundPosition": "+=350 -=150"}, 500);
```

[jsfiddle with different rules, because I didn't want to find a background image.](http://jsfiddle.net/NRBAt/2/)